# Прошу помощи в решении задачи на питоне

Tags: python

Уже больше двух недель не могу разобраться с задачей,нужно использовать цикл for  и тд. Прошу помощи и подробных объяснений,обучаюсь несколько месяцев.
Для коров есть 10 стойл. В каждом стойле разные условия для животных, поэтому и молока они дают по-разному. В первом стойле производят 2 литра в день, во втором 4, в третьем - 6, потом 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20. Но коровы стоят не во всех стойлах. Свободные и занятые обозначаются строкой из букв a и b, где a - свободное стойло, b - занятое.

Пользователь вводит строку из 10 символов a и b. Необходимо определить, сколько в итоге будет произведено молока за день.

Comment: Пока вас не закидали ссылками на правила, просто сообщаю - если у вас учебные задания, кидайте код, который у вас уже есть.

Comment: Покажите Вашу попытку реализации подправим что не так. Просто писать ответы на учебную задачу как то не принято. Можно набросать примерный алгоритм если поможет.

Comment: Я вот вчера первый раз узнал про Питон и у меня здесь только два вопроса: как вы получаете строку от пользователя? Из командной строки промптом? И как работать со строкой как с массивом?

Comment: @Leonid Строку от пользователя проще всего получить через `input`. А как с массивом со строкой можно работать множеством способов - просто перебирая её как коллекцию, а способов перебора коллекций есть несколько.

Comment: @CrazyElf, спасибо. Я попробую решить эту задачу без двух недель пыхтения и долгих месяцев обучения)))

Comment: Из вариантов первое что пришло в голову создать словарь {n-стойла: литры}. А дальше просто по строке идем и подставляем индексы если b то + к сумме

Comment: @Александр Невский, почему вы врете?

Comment: [Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), проголосуйте за ответ и отметьте его [галочкой](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) как решение.

Answer (score 4):

Поскольку это тестовое задание, вы его должны решить сами. Но могу дать подсказку - эта задача решается в одну строчку при использовании `range`, `zip`, `sum` и *спискового включения*.

P.S. Ну раз все уже пишут код, придётся и мне код привести.

```
print(sum(v for k,v in zip(input(), range(2,22,2)) if k == 'b'))
```

Answer (score 3):

```
milk_yield = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20]
cow_stalls = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b']

result = sum(m[1] for m in list(zip(cow_stalls, milk_yield)) if m[0]=='b')
```

В `result` - сумма молока от коров в занятых стойлах:

```
>>> result
64
```

---

список кортежей, каждый элемент которого - код стойла и удой:

```
>>> list(zip(cow_stalls, milk_yield))
[('a', 2), ('a', 4), ('b', 6), ('a', 8), ('b', 10), ('b', 12), ('a', 14), ('b', 16), ('a', 18), ('b', 20)]
```

цикл по этому списку:

```
m[1] for m in...
```

учитывая только занятые стойла:

```
if m[0]=='b'
```

Comment: можно без `list`

Answer (score 1):

В продолжение комментариев вариант кода:

```py
s = "baaaaaaaab"
milk = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20]
summ = 0
for n, i in enumerate(s):
    if i == "b":
        summ += milk[n]

print(summ)
```

Comment: Так массив обозначается круглыми или квадратными скобками?

Comment: Понял, `list` еще есть... Я пока до коллекций не дошел. Так, интуитивно набрал))

Comment: Посмотрите отличие списки и кортежи, мой код можно переписать и в [] ничего не изменится особо. Подправлю что-бы не путать)

Answer (score 0):

Простите, что нарушаю солидарность в вопросах ответа на учебные задания, но я сам вчера только начала изучать Python и мне это интересно. Прошу прокомментировать ответ, если что не так.

```
udoi = [2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20]

print('Введите строку без пробелов из букв a и b,латинскими, пожалуйста')
string = input()

moloko = 0

for i in range(10):
    if string[i] == 'b':
        moloko += udoi[i]

print(moloko)
```

Comment: что значат квадратные скобки?

Comment: Кто из нас месяцы провел за обучением языка? У меня другой вопрос: ругается VSCode на `print` но запускаю и все нормально работает, что не так?

Comment: @АлександрНевский а вы точно "больше двух недель не могу разобраться"? квадратные скобки должны были встретиться в одном из первых разделов по типам пайтона ;)

Comment: Как то все сложно... а почему  если =="a" то udoy =1 а не 0. Ведь стойло пустое.

Comment: @Kers, верно исправил

Comment: @Jack_oS даа,точно,я обучаюсь на скиллбоксе,и пока что про кв. скобки не говорили..

Comment: @Leonid если b - просто добавляйте литры к результату, не усложняйте... или пользуйте булевые значения и делайте True там, где есть корова, а не наоборот

Comment: из нюансов переменная udoy можно и без не сделать

Comment: @Jack_oS сделал, пытался как в JS `moloko+=udoi[i]` , но так нельзя видимо

Comment: как бы так и делается но у Вас там не индекс только.. Сек дополню свой вариант если уж пошло такое дело...

Answer (score 0):

Подкину немного тем для изучения Python:

```
udoi = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20]
string = ['a', 'a', 'b','a', 'b','a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a']

print(sum(u[1] for u in zip(string, udoi) if u[0] == 'b'))
```

Comment: Обычно `_` подразумевает ненужную переменную но Вы ее все-же используете потом в коде.  Ну и да это работает конечно но читаемость портится.

Comment: Я думаю, что это дело привычки. Ведь она же и не нужная. Мы получаем из зипа объект с буквой и значением. Обработали ее и забыли, получив сумму.

Comment: **Обработали ее** - это противоречит концепции использования `_`, она именно что используется когда переменная вообще никак не обрабатывется

Comment: Ок. Глянул конвенцию. Спасибо) Поправил)